# Cognitive Behavioral Therapy 101

Tags: cognitive-psychology

Let's say that I'm completely green about psychology and CBT (like I really know nothing, apart from that CBT exists). Is there a good introduction/ seminal work, but with relatively low barrier of entry and not too massive (something that could be learned/ studied in several evenings)?

I'm aware of [this question](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/3768/comprehensive-list-of-cognitive-techniques-in-cbt), but what I'm looking for specifically is a book or a more involved/ in-depth resource.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should look at one of the more well rated books on [CBT](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_sc_1_9?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=cognitive%20behavior%20therapy&sprefix=cognitive%2Cstripbooks%2C347).

Aaron beck is the father of CBT so maybe start with his [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1609185048) if you can't make a decision.

Comment: I'll maybe try to be a bit more specific: I'm not trying to help myself, and most of top-rated CBT books you've linked to are self-help -- my interest is CBT is more academic than clinical as well, so step-by-step clinical programs are of no interest to me either. The suggestion of trying out Aaron Beck is probably more relevant.

Comment: For a thorough understanding I would have a look at the Handbook of Cognitive-Behavioral Therapies

http://www.amazon.com/Handbook-Cognitive-Behavioral-Therapies-Third-Edition/dp/1606234374

Comment: Or for a quick overview have a look at chapter 8 in volume 8 of the Handbook of Psychology http://au.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470917997.html